# For a keras model with multiple outputs how do I introduce a custom loss that takes them all as input arguments?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I have been trying code like the example below. The keras model is created with a list of two outputs. I believe that means I need a list of two y's, so I have that.

The custom loss assumes y_pred and y_true are lists, but they are not. It crashes because they are tensors.

`` OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature. ``

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf

n_samples = 1000
n_features = 10
X = np.random.random((n_samples, n_features))
Y = [np.random.random((n_samples, 1)),
     np.random.random((n_samples, 1))]

class CustomLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # Assuming y_true and y_pred are lists of tensors
        y_true1, y_true2 = y_true
        y_pred1, y_pred2 = y_pred

        mse1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true1 - y_pred1))
        mse2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true2 - y_pred2))

        return mse1 + mse2

# Define the model
input_layer = Input(shape=(n_features,))
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_layer)
outputs = [Dense(1)(x), Dense(1)(x)]

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=CustomLoss())

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

I'm on tensorflow 2.8.4

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced this is not supported. Keras will work its way into any dict or list you give it to find each Tensor, and call the loss on each one. If you want multiple outputs to go to one loss - I'm just going to concatenate them and unpack them in the loss. The other idea I saw was to package them in a Tensorflow Probablity Distribution. From re-reading the Keras API doc

*If the model has multiple outputs, you can use a different loss on each output by passing a dictionary or a list of losses. The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the sum of all individual losses, unless loss_weights is specified.*

I'm not sure this suggests that multiple outputs can be passsed to one loss.